# Trigger IBAction in all open NSDocuments

Tags: cocoa, swift, document, nswindow

I am changing various things like layer background colours, font colours etc etc.. The process starts with an IBAction in the view controller (seen below) when my user clicks a button in the documents window. Currently this works, but is only affecting the active window in my OS X document based application.

If there are multiple document windows open at the same time I'd like the changes to affect all the open windows, not just the active one.

It only affects all the windows after re-launching the app currently.

[image]

Thank's to accepted answer below :

In the window controller add :

```
    @IBAction func themeButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        var thetag = sender.tag()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("updateTheme", object: nil, userInfo: ["tag": thetag])
    }

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "handleNotification:", name: "updateTheme", object: nil)
    }

    func handleNotification(notification:NSNotification){
        let userInfo:Dictionary<String,Int!> = notification.userInfo as Dictionary<String,Int!>
        let thetag:Int = userInfo["tag"]!
        switch thetag {
        case 0 :
            theCurrentTheme = "white"
            Defaults["theme"] = "white"
        case 1 :
            theCurrentTheme = "cream"
            Defaults["theme"] = "cream"
        case 2 :
            theCurrentTheme = "black"
            Defaults["theme"] = "black"
        default:
            theCurrentTheme = "white"
            Defaults["theme"] = "white"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, if you want to make the change available to any open document, and the triggering party doesn't know which or how many documents are open, you should post an `NSNotification`, and have the interested parties listen to it (register to it).

So, in addition to the window controllers enacting the change as a response to their buttons' `IBAction`s, they could also register for the notification (eventually posted by another instance of the window controller) and do the exact same thing as when the button was pressed.

**ADDENDUM:** You should call the actual method that performs the changes **only from the notification handler**, and from within the `IBAction` you should only post the notification. Otherwise, the window controller that triggered the action will perform the changes ***twice***!

...which means, you no longer need a separate, private method (it is being called from only one place), and can instead code the logic for the changes inside the notification handler.

Comment: You could put all the logic to effect the changes in one private method, and call that **both** from the `IBAction` **and** the notification handler.

Comment: Thank's man.. Light at the end of the tunnel. So I register a listener for a notification in windowDidLoad() in window controller. Put all the logic that changes my UI theme in a method in the window controller. Post the notification from the IBAction in the diagram. And run the private method when the notification is received. And even the inactive open windows will respond to the notification and run their instance of the private method..?

Comment: I guess the window controllers should receive the notification as long as the instances haven't been deallocated, regardless of if their windows are active or not. `NSNotificationCenter` has nothing to do with window focus/active document. Remember to unregister in `dealloc`, otherwise "zombie apocalypse" will ensue!

Comment: Oops, just discovered a bug in my solution! See edits.

Comment: Thank's Nicolas, This certainly sounds like the solution. 2am here, so I'll get back with a big green tick in the morning :-)